# Trap non interactive element's focus

Tags: reactjs, focus, accessibility

I have an non interactive element like a div on the page that serves as a loading modal. When it is loading, I want to show this modal as well as the rest of the page containing interactive elements with a opacity of 50%. When it is loading(loading modal shows up), I want the focus trapped in this modal and make it so the user cannot tab through the rest of the elements on the page. I've tried the code below by adding the ReactFocusLock around the div and give the div a tabIndex of -1 so it is focusable and set it to be focusable at the beginning but it does not work. However, if I put a link or something interactable inside the div, it works well, which means the ReactFocusLock is fine. Could you please help?

```
const MyComponent = () => {
 const {loading, data} = fetchData();
 return <>
  {loading && <LoadingModal />}
  {data && <div>data</div>}
  <input></input>
  <button></button>
 <>;
}

// original modal
const LoadingModal = () => {
 return <div>loading data....<div>; 
}

// modal that with ReactFocusLock from react-focus-lock 
const LoadingModal = () => {
 const ref = React.useRef(null);
 React.useEffect(() => {
      ref.current.focus();
 }, []);
 return <ReactFocusLock><div ref={ref} tabIndex={-1}>loading data....</div></ReactFocusLock>;
}
```

Comment: `<ReactFocusLock>` doesn't work for screen readers. It stops Tabbing and that appears to be it after a quick test. To truly trap focus in a modal for everybody you need to add `tabindex="-1"` to every other interactive element on the page and also add `aria-hidden="true"` to all containers outside the modal (so the modal needs to sit outside the `<main>` element). This truly hides all elements on the page for everybody. (The reason it doesn't work for screen readers is they navigate using links, headings, sections etc. more than using Tab so you need to stop that as well by hiding everything.)

Comment: I was thinking the reason ReactFocusLock does not work is it cannot trap focus of an element with tabIndex=-1, since when I set a noniteractive element with tabIndex=0 is work fine. So a workaround I am current trying is give the div a tabIndex=0 and now it traps its focus. The rest of the element are a lot and it is kind of impossible for me to give them all  tabindex="-1" and aria-hidden="true"

Comment: Sorry I confused things. `ReactFocusLock` requires an internal item that is focusable to work, that is correct (hence why `tabindex="-1"` doesn't work, it needs one focusable item). What I am saying is it doesn't actually work properly even if you do that, all it does is stop you **tabbing** outside the modal. Screen reader users do not normally navigate via Tab so that causes a problem where they can leave the modal.

Comment: Sorry, what I learn is tabindex=-1 make the element can't be tabbed to but focus can be given to the element programmatically (using element.focus()).